# Solve a ODE for arrays of parameters (Python)

Tags: python, scipy

*I am aware that this question is quite simple but I would like to know the best way to set up such a for loop in Python.

I have written a program already to calculate and plot the solution to a 2nd order differential equation (this code is given below).

I would like to know best methods for repeating this calculation for an array of f parameters (hence `f_array`). I.e. so that the plot shows `20` sets of data referring to solutions as a function of `t` each with a different value of `f`.

Cheers for any ideas.

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.integrate import odeint

#Arrays.
tmax = 100
t = linspace(0, tmax, 4000)
fmax = 100
f_array = linspace(0.0, fmax, 20)

#Parameters
l = 2.5
w0 = 0.75
f = 5.0
gamma = w0 + 0.05
m = 1.0
alpha = 0.15
beta = 2.5

def rhs(c,t):
    c0dot = c[1]
    c1dot = -2*l*c[1] - w0*w0*c[0] + (f/m)*cos((gamma)*t)-alpha*c[0] - beta*c[0]*c[0]*c[0]
    return [c0dot, c1dot]

init_x = 15.0
init_v = 0.0
init_cond = [init_x,init_v]
ces = odeint(rhs, init_cond, t)

s_no = 1
subplot(s_no,1,1)
xlabel("Time, t")
ylabel("Position, x")
grid('on')
plot(t,ces[:,0],'-b')
title("Position x vs. time t for a Duffing oscillator.")
show()
```

Here is a plot showing the solution to this equation regarding a single value of `f` for an array of `t` values. I would like a quick way to repeat this plot for an array of `f` values.

[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/28bgyzs.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach:

Modify `rhs` to accept a third argument, the parameter `f`.  The definition of `rhs` should begin

```
def rhs(c, t, f):
    ...
```

Iterate over the `f_array` with a `for` loop.  In the loop, call `odeint` with the `args` argument so that `odeint` gives the value of `f` as the third argument to `rhs`.  Save the results of each call to `odeint` in a list.  Basically, replace

```
ces = odeint(rhs, init_cond, t)
```

with

```
solutions = []
for f in f_array:
    ces = odeint(rhs, init_cond, t, args=(f,))
    solutions.append(ces)
```

For each value of `f` in `f_array`, you now have a solution in the `solutions` list.

To plot these, you could put your `plot` call in another `for` loop:

```
for ces in solutions:
    plot(t, ces[:, 0], 'b-')
```

Comment: Good suggestion, thank you. I have managed  How do I then go onto separate each solution from the list of arrays for plotting?

Comment: You can put the call to `plot` in a loop over `solutions`.  See the updated answer.