# python scipy odeint return values

Tags: scipy, odeint

I have been playing around with odeint in scipy and I could not understand what the function returns as return values. For example,

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Feb 04 20:01:16 2017

@author: Esash
"""

from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def MassSpring(state,t):
  # unpack the state vector
  x = state[0]
  xd = state[1]

  # these are our constants
  k = -5.5 # Newtons per metre
  m = 1.5 # Kilograms
  g = 9.8 # metres per second

  # compute acceleration xdd
  xdd = ((k*x)/m) + g

  # return the two state derivatives
  return [xd, xdd]

state0 = [0.0, 0.0]
t = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1)

state = odeint(MassSpring, state0, t)

plt.plot(t, state)
plt.xlabel('TIME (sec)')
plt.ylabel('STATES')
plt.title('Mass-Spring System')
plt.legend(('$x$ (m)', '$\dot{x}$ (m/sec)'))
```

In the above code, I have set the two parameters as 0.0 and 0.0 and the xd in the function is just 0.0 which I return as well. But the return value is not just 0.0, it varies.

```
In [14]: state
Out[14]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.04885046,  0.97402207],
       [ 0.19361613,  1.91243899],
       ..., 
       [ 0.10076832, -1.39206172],
       [ 0.00941998, -0.42931942],
       [ 0.01542821,  0.54911655]])
```

Also, if I have one differential equation for which I need to send many parameters, then I cannot send M parameters in the odeint call as a list or tuple  and return only the solution of the ODE as a single array. It expects that the number of parameters sent should be equal to the number of parameters returned form the function. Why is this?

I am not able to understand how this function works. Can someone please explain this to me? My apologies if I sound too confusing.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> I could not understand what the function returns as return values.

The return value of `odeint` is the computed solution at the requested time values.  That is, after this call

```
state = odeint(MassSpring, state0, t)
```

`state[0]` is [x(t[0]), x'(t[0])], `state[1]` is [x(t[1]), x'(t[1])], etc.  If you wanted to plot just the `x` coordinate, you could call `plt.plot(t, state[:, 0])` to plot the first column of `state`.

> I have set the two parameters as 0.0 and 0.0 [...]

What you are calling the "parameters" are usually called the *initial conditions*.  They are the values of x(t) and x'(t) at t=0.

> But the return value is not just 0.0, it varies.

That is because (0, 0) is not an equilibrium of the system. Look at the equation

```
xdd = ((k*x)/m) + g
```

When `x` is 0, you get `xdd = g`, so `xdd` is initially positive.  That is, there is a nonzero force (gravity) acting on the mass, so it accelerates.

The equilibrium state is [-g*m/k, 0].

> Also, if I have one differential equation for which I need to send many parameters, then I cannot send M parameters in the odeint call as a list or tuple and return only the solution of the ODE as a single array. It expects that the number of parameters sent should be equal to the number of parameters returned form the function. Why is this?

`odeint` only solves the system for one set of initial conditions at a time.  If you want to generate several solutions (corresponding to different initial conditions), you'll have to call `odeint` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cleared up my doubts exactly. But in the last question, I meant, if I have an equation like: 

xdd = ((k*x*a)/m) + g

where a is some value that I need to pass to the solver, then I cannot do it with odeint or I am not sure how to do it. If I try sending in additional parameters, then it throws an error. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: To pass additional parameters to your functions, you can use the `args` argument.  See the example in [the `odeint` docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).  More examples: http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/CoupledSpringMassSystem.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001341/having-trouble-while-using-scipy-integrate-odeint-with-python/16008005#16008005, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891972/solve-a-ode-for-arrays-of-parameters-python